# Xcode 10.1 How to fix User Interface Inspector "Capturing User Interface" not working continuously loads

Tags: xcode, user-interface, xcode10.1

I updated to Xcode 10.1 today, and noticed that when trying to utilize the User Interface Inspector that it continuously loads.  I utilize this feature a lot to check how constraints are behaving.  Was wondering if anyone else had the same issue?

Steps that I have taken to try and resolve it:

- Reset all simulator data
- Cleared all derived data
- Cleaned build
- Tried multiple simulators with the same issue

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. Creating a new simulator on the latest iOS that came with Xcode fixed it for me.